# Had to restore site, when it came back it has index.php in the urls, how do I get rid of the index.php

Tags: magento-1, url, redirect

Would like to say thank you up front for your help!!!  I have **magento 1.4.0.1**, I AM NOT A COMPUTER GEEK by any stretch of the word.  I do not have a developer so if someone can help answer this being very specific, step by step I would really appreciate it!!

I was trying to get an Amazon payment button on our site.  To make a long story short, I had to restore the site, when the site was back up and functioning in the URL's Index.php was present.

> **/index.php/admin/dashboard/**
>
> **index.php/womens-gifts/purse-hooks.html**

Since this has happened I also have **6800 NOT FOUND errors on Google webmasters**.   Please for customer friendly circumstance and the Holidays coming I need to get this off.  I have spoke to our server support and they informed me that there was 3 access points  **`.htaccess`** file code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

Can somebody help me please.  However then they said if I made a mistake I could do something major to the site and I found this site, so I am hoping to get some help, help that I can understand, Thanks Again  Tracy

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 things to do:

1. check your **`.htaccess`** (seems that you already tried that)

   a. Do you use **Apache as webserver**? If it's **Nginx** then **`.htaccess`** is not used

   b. Some hosting companies override or disable **`.htaccess`** for security reasons
2. check that you have Use Web Server **Rewrites = Yes** under **`System/Configuration/General/Web/Search Engine Optimization`**